# Can an extension require other extensions and call functions from them?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension for multiple languages. I'd like to have just a single core extension, and then make the code for each language a separate extension. Is it possible to do this? The core extension would essentially need to be able to recognize that the others are installed and call some of their code.

Comment: Why do you want to structure your project like this?

Comment: In part to reduce the extension size -- no need for a bunch of language-specific stuff for languages you don't use. Also, I'd like others people to be able to develop their own extensions that plug into the core one I'm building.

Comment: Suggestion: Put the language agnostic stuff into an assembly of its own and reference it from the language specific assemblies. Publish the language agnostic assembly for others to use

Comment: By "assembly" do you mean just make the core an npm package? That's certainly an option, but it would result in multiple instances of the core code running. It's a possible approach, although I'm still interested to know if my original question is possible.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. For the original question, I don't know, that'S for others to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible via the [`extensions` API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_extensions) - extensions can return an API from their `activate()` method:

```ts
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let api = {
        sum(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        },
        mul(a, b) {
            return a * b;
        }
    };
    // 'export' public api-surface
    return api;
}
```

And another extension can then retrieve and use that API via a `getExtension()` call:

```ts
let mathExt = extensions.getExtension('genius.math');
let importedApi = mathExt.exports;

console.log(importedApi.mul(42, 1));
```

A list of all extensions known to VSCode is also available via `extensions.all`.